# Get every variable loop value in array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

How to get every variable of loop into an array and call all the variables in some other variable.

I am very new to array. I don't have any idea how to solve this.

Suppose I have an `Array[]`

and the variable in an array is `i`, so `i1, i2, i3 ....... in`

`n` is the number of times loop will run.

So

```
for (i=1; i<=n, i++) {

//I need an array called here.

//there will be some code play here

//There will be some value returned after the code it could be text or no.

}
```

then I want to assign all the values of array into a variable with comma separated

```
var k = array{}  i.e k = "i1,i2,i3,......in"
```

I try to find on Google but not able to find any solution.

This example is a reference for what I want to achieve actually.

Comment: please format your question. it's hard to read and understand

Comment: You don't call arrays

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer How did you edit the question in such a clean way?

Comment: I used [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), which is a nice text-based way of specifying rich text formatting.

Comment: @halfer Oh great, I was not aware of that. Thanks

Comment: @halfer I don't know if someone appreciated your work or not but you are the legend on here. You edit the question in a structured way. It makes any person understand the problem and share his answer. Thanks for the help.
In future i will edit the question in that way. :)

Comment: Thanks @PiyushVerma, it is nice for editing work to be appreciated. Most folks don't notice it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will declare the array before you enter the for loop. You will then perform your logic and .push() the new values into the array inside of the for loop. After the for loop, you would then want to .join() the array. This will assign the values of your array as a string to your new variable.

```
var yourArray = [];
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    // some logic...
    yourArray.push(newValue);
}
var yourNewVariable = yourArray.join(", ");
```

Comment: Yes, This solves half of my problem. thanks alot.
How to make an array and assign variable to it. Please can you show me an example as per my given example

Comment: So before your loop you will want to create the array with `var yourArray = []`. Then in your loop you will push the values you want to store into your array `yourArray.push(newValue)`.

Comment: I am going to check, Thanks a lot for very fast help. How can i rate your profile or something related.

Comment: If you find my answer to be correct, you can press the check mark to the left of the answer to "accept" it as correct.

Comment: I did, I am working on the script if I get some error, I will catch you up.
Thanks a ton again

Answer (score 1):

While this should be very easy to Google, here's how you do it:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= k.length; i++) {
    var item = k[i];
    // ...do something with item
}
```

When you become more versed in JS, look into using `.forEach` or `.map`:

```
k.forEach(function(item) {
    // ...do something with item
});
```

Comment: my answer is more geared toward how to get the item in the array, but did not fully answer the question

Comment: Still Thanks for the help man, I think ken has solved my problem. But thanks for giving time mate. God bless you and Ken